# xvkbd broken with warnings

Tags: keyboard, bind

I'm using the latest version of Ubuntu and I can't run `xvkbd` properly. I get these errors:

```
$ xvkbd
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-lucidatypewriter-bold-r-*-*-12-*-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1" to type FontStruct
xvkbd: Mode_switch not available as a modifier
xvkbd: although ISO_Level3_Shift is used instead, AltGr may not work correctly
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-lucida-bold-i-*-*-14-*-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1" to type FontStruct
xvkbd: Mode_switch not available as a modifier
xvkbd: although ISO_Level3_Shift is used instead, AltGr may not work correctly
```

How can i solve this? I'm trying to use this with `xbindkeys`.

Comment: how do i install the correct font packages...

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-fonts xfonts-75dpi xfonts-100dpi
```

for sun-java6-fonts you need sun java JRE, you can get it here: https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6

Answer (score 1):

In Debian 7 (Wheezy), my xvkbd-provided virtual keyboard looked great and threw no font-related squawks after I loaded just the `xfonts-75dpi` package.

UPDATE: Beware of this procedure. After I upgraded to Debian 8 (Jessie), some web pages I printed to PDF ended up with ugly, bit-mapped fonts. The problem went away, however, after I installed (in **ttf** format) the Lucida and Helvetica fonts that **xvkbd** was looking for.